# How to join two wav files together not one after the other

Tags: audio

How to join two wav files together not one after the other? I know how to combine the files one by one, but I do not know how to unite them so that overlap.

Comment: The answer depends strongly on the platform you use. On un*x install sox. `sox -m file1.wav file2.wav output.wav` will do the trick.

Comment: On Linux, Yes I used sox, but sox get a error `sox FAIL sox: Input files must have the same sample-rate
sox FAIL sox: Input files must have the same # channels`

Comment: Then you can first convert them to the same sample rate with sox. Then downmix both to mono (or create a stereo file from the mono one by duplicating the channel). And then use `sox -m`.

Comment: Ok, I no longer this error. It was: `sox sox FAIL: Input files must have the same # channels`

Comment: Ok, I correct this `ffmpeg -i video.flv -ab 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vn audio.mp3` `-ac 2` two channels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WAV file format is a chunked layout, typically with a header at the front specifying the format, then a data chunk with the audio data. This is why you can't simply cat the 2 files together.

If this something you only need to do once, you can download a free audio editor such as Audicity, load both files in and then save out the appended version.

Good luck!